# How to repeat LIKE pattern 'n' times

Tags: sql-server

I would like repeat LIKE pattern 7 times in my queries.

```
SELECT count(displayName),
AS nbDisplayNameDefaut
FROM users
WHERE displayName LIKE 'user[0123456789]'
```

This query return all display name like userX but i would like to have seven time numbers to have display name like this userXXXXXXX (X is numbers)

I think that this query is not optimized if I make this :

```
LIKE 'user[0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789][0123456789]'
```

I don't find the option in SQL-Server doc

Comment: Looks good to me, you are essentially doing a pattern match which is probably the quickest you are going to perform this query on the current data set. Have you checked the query plan?

Comment: It's working but i would like to know if an option exists to have a shorter pattern

Comment: Sql doesn't support regex, but you can always create a CLR function that does the regex. I suppose you want something like `user[0-9]{7}` etc. I don't think sql like supports any more concise patterns

Comment: @Charleh, SQL Server supports `LIKE 'user[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'`, albeit not especially concise.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

SQL Server LIKE supports range patterns so you can use `[0-9]` instead of `[01234567899]` for a single decimal digit. This pattern can be replicated for the number of digits desired for a more concise expression:

```
LIKE 'user' + REPLICATE('[0-9]', 7)
```