# Repetition of expressions in SQL LIKE

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex

Is there a way to express repetition in SQL LIKE.
I have the following query that matches 4 or 5 digits, then a hyphen, and then 8 additional digits:

```
SELECT * FROM Table
WHERE Field LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
   OR Field LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

In other languages I would write something like this: `[0-9]{4-5}-[0-9]{8}`.
Is there a way to simplify the above expression in SQL?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to repeat LIKE pattern 'n' times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41198172/how-to-repeat-like-pattern-n-times)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like SQL Server.  You could construct the strings:

```
select '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]',
       replicate('[0-9]', 4) + '-' + replicate('[0-9]', 8)
```

However, SQL Server doesn't have built-in regular expression support.

Answer (score 1):

Below are the equivalent regular expressions,

**Oracle**

```
`REGEXP_LIKE(X, '^[[:digit:]]+$');`
```

**PostgreSql**

```
 `like '%[1-9]%' `
```

Comment: I believe this question is for SQL Server, rather than Oracle or PostgreSQL.